# I update the range slider value but it does not display visually

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, rangeslider

Sometimes the value of a slider changes depending on a variable. When this happens, I set my-slider.value = newValue, and it changes. But it is not shown visually, that is, the slider still shows the previous value. What should I do?

```js
var newValue;

function calcNV() {
  async function delayedGreeting() {

    altitude = document.getElementById("altitude-slider");
    limit = document.getElementById("limit-slider");

    if (altitude.value == 1000) {
      limit.value = newValue = 90;
    }
    if (altitude.value == 1500) {
      limit.value = newValue = 89;
    }
    if (altitude.value == 2000) {
      limit.value = newValue = 88;
    }

    $('#obj-ntydnn448').text(newValue + "%");
  }
  delayedGreeting();
}

// SPO2 Limit
function updateLimit(val) {
  $('#obj-ntydnn448').text(val + "%");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-cell flex-shrink-3">
  <div class="range-slider range-slider-init color-f66907">
    <input type="range" min="70" max="90" step="1" value="88" id="limit-slider" onchange="updateLimit(this.value);" oninput="updateLimit(value);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Frist welcome to SO. Second, add your code. We can not help you without your code

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know exactly what your problem is, but what are describing sounds a lot like the common issue: Updating an inputs value with JS doesn't trigger the change event. Which may well be preventing any library affecting your sliders appearance from updating.

Comment: where is the element with `id: obj-ntydnn448`